# ReactiveUI : WPF Two way binding not working as expected

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, reactiveui

I am working on a WPF application using reactiveui, and am having difficulty getting two way binding working in my custom dependency property. I can get this working using WPF binding but not using the reactiveui.

I have a user control called IPAddressControl, which takes in an IP address input and provides a dependency property ValidIpAddress, shown below.

```
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ValidIpAddressProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            "ValidIpAddress",
            typeof(bool),
            typeof(IPAddressControl),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
                false,
                FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault,
                new PropertyChangedCallback(OnValidIpAddressPropertyChanged)));

    public bool ValidIpAddress
    {
        get
        {
            return (bool)GetValue(ValidIpAddressProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(ValidIpAddressProperty, value);
        }
    }

    private static void OnValidIpAddressPropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        IPAddressControl IPAddressControl = d as IPAddressControl;
        IPAddressControl.ValidIpAddress = (bool)e.NewValue;
    }
```

In my view, I set up the binding as follows :

```
public partial class MyView : ReactiveUserControl<MyViewModel>

    public MyView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        ViewModel = new MyViewModel();

        this.WhenActivated(view =>
        {
           this.Bind(ViewModel, vm => vm.ValidIpAddress,     v => v.ipaddress.ValidIpAddress);
        });
    }
```

And define my view model property

```
public class MyViewModel : ReactiveObject
{
    bool _validIpAddress = false;
    public bool ValidIpAddress
    {
        get => this._validIpAddress;
        set => this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _validIpAddress, value);
    }
}
```

When the property gets updated in IPAddressControl

```
IPAddressControl.ValidIPaddress = true;
```

I would expect MyViewModel.ValidIpAddress.Set to be called, however this is not happening.

When I revert to the standard WPF implementation, the two way binding works well, i.e. I set the binding in the myview.xaml

```
ValidIpAddress="{Binding Path=ValidIpAddress}"
```

then set the data context in constructor MyView();

```
this.DataContext = new MyViewModel()
```

So it appears I am doing something wrong in relation to the reactiveui binding.

I'd appreciate if someone could help.

Thanks.

Comment: OnValidIpAddressPropertyChanged is a bit strange. Eg your just setting the value back on the control again. Could be causing you issues and you may want to remove.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but when I remove this, the binding that I did get working, when I revert to standard WPF binding fails to work.

Comment: Btw we don't use DataContext in rxui but the ViewModel property.

Comment: Yes, agreed. When I use only the ViewModel property, my dependency property binding doesn't work. Other bindings do work, however. I reverted to the standard WPF data binding to verify that the dependency property actually works.